# Screen is blinking while playing video on vlc!

Tags: video, pi-4, vlc, media

I am using PI4 with raspbian buster.
While I am playing videos on VLC the screen sometimes blink.
The blinking interval is random. Is it normal or is there a problem that is needed to be fixed?

Comment: Is Raspbian fully updated? What file are you playing?

Comment: Raspberry pi is fully upgraded. I am playing a movie. An mp4 file

Comment: What happens if you use omxplayer?

Comment: Never used it. Don't know. VLC is easy to use. So I am searching for a solution

Comment: Maybe a screen recording would help find a solution.

Comment: and how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use VLC on the latest Buster and RPi4. I remember getting some screen blinking when I used a crappy HDMI cable which I have since replaced. One easy test you can do is changing the screen resolution to a lower one, e.g. 1280x720. You can do this e.g. by editing `/boot/config.txt`, running `raspi-config` (those two require a reboot), by going to Application Menu > Preferences, or using command line by running `sudo tvservice -e "CEA 4"`. If the blinking goes away or is substantially reduced, your problem is likely in the cable, and you should get a shorter one if possible, and from a shop those quality you trust.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Screen flickering is attributed due to low power supply.
Please check at the top right of your screen you will see a yellow thunder icon if that is the case.

Comment: nothing is there